# unresolved import 'GUI.py' Python(unresolved-import) when importing functions from code in same directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to call functions from separate python files within the same folder directory but receiving the following error within VSCode.

```
unresolved import 'IXL_main.py'Python(unresolved-import)
```

When trying to run the code directly I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TMS_main.py", line 30, in <module>
    from TMS_threading import globalStopAllTrains
ImportError: cannot import name 'globalStopAllTrains' from 'TMS_threading' (C:\Users\....\TMS_threading.py)
```

I've tried the following:

- Refresh VSCode
- Refresh & Check Python Interpreter
- Reinstalling VSCode
- Re-Typing Import Modules & Files
- Creating and adding .env file and path to settings.json

Comment: What is TMS_threading and where is it located? Same for `IXL_main`. It would be helpful if you could show the folder structure and the exact import statements you are using (e.g. that `IXL_main.py` looks like you are writing an import like `import IXL_main.py` which would be wrong as you would want `import IXL_main`).

Answer (score 0):

I need more information.

So you have two files in the same folder. You run the first file with Python (`python first_file.py`). This `first_file` imports the second one like this:
`from second_file import your_function`. Then, still in your first file, the command `your_function(arguments)` raises this error ?

Answer (score -2):

Search 'jedi' in the settings to replace Microsoft Python Analysis Engine

Comment: Can you provide a little more context, esp. how `jedi` causes this problem?